# SwiftUI NavigationStack always pops to root

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I have recently updated the navigation in my app from using lots of NavigationLinks, because I was seeing errors surrounding multiple pushes to the navigation stack.

My app is now working well with a custom navcontroller that programatically adds views to the stack, but there is one issue with when I try to pop back to the previous view using the back button on the toolbar it always pops all the way back to the root going through all the child views one by one.

Here is an overview of the current setup:

**Navigation Controller -**

```
class NavigationController: ObservableObject {

@Published var homeNavPath: [AppView] = []

public func navigateTo(destination: AppView) {
      homeNavPath.append(destination)
}
```

}

**Navigation Stack -**

```
 NavigationStack(path: $navController.homeNavPath) {
     HomeView()
 }
```

**Navigation Example -**

```
public struct HomeView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var navController: NavigationController

    public var body: some View {
        Text("GO TO POST").onTapGesture {
            navController.navigateTo(PostView("123"))
        }
    }
}


public struct PostView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var navController: NavigationController

    public var body: some View {
        Text("GO TO USER").onTapGesture {
            navController.navigateTo(UserView("123"))
        }
    }
}

public struct UserView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var navController: NavigationController

    public var body: some View {
        Text("USER INFORMATION...")
    }
}
```

I am able to perfectly navigate from Home -> Post -> User as expected, but when I press the back button on the user page, it will always navigate back to the root (e.g home in this case) no matter how long the navigation path it.

Here is an example, I only press the back button once here:

[example navigation gif](https://imgur.com/a/w9NwYOb)

Let me know if there is any more information that could help and thanks for any suggestions

Comment: What is `AppView`? Do you get the same effect if `homeNavPath` is set to a `NavigationPath()` object? In my experience, using an array of custom objects as a path is best used for objects that you use with values (e.g. `NavigationLink(value: ...) { }` and `.navigationDestination(for: ...)`. If you want to push views but have the control that a stateful stack gives you, `NavigationPath()` might be the way to go.

Comment: AppView is just an enum that represents the views I can navigate too. I tried replacing the AppView array with NavigationPath but still faced the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure what your `AppView` enum looked like, but here's a working version of the code you provided.

A quick note: I would suggest you move `NavigationPath` directly into whichever view owns the `NavigationStack` as a `@State` property (that way you can use `NavigationLink`s and not have to pass `navController` through `environmentObject` modifiers).

```
@main
struct StackDeleteApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            HomeCoordinatorView()
        }
    }
}

enum AppView: Hashable {
    case postView(String)
    case userView(String)
}

class NavigationController: ObservableObject {
    @Published var homeNavPath = NavigationPath()

    func navigateTo(_ destination: AppView) {
        homeNavPath.append(destination)
    }
}

struct HomeCoordinatorView: View {
    @StateObject var navController = NavigationController()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navController.homeNavPath) {
             HomeView()
                .environmentObject(navController)
                .navigationDestination(for: AppView.self) { appView in
                    switch appView {
                    case .postView(let post):
                        PostView(post: post)
                            .environmentObject(navController)
                    case .userView(let user):
                        UserView(user: user)
                            .environmentObject(navController)
                    }
                }
         }
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navController: NavigationController

    var body: some View {
        Text("GO TO USER").onTapGesture {
            navController.navigateTo(.userView("123"))
        }
    }
}

struct PostView: View {
    let post: String
    @EnvironmentObject var navController: NavigationController

    var body: some View {
        Text("GO TO USER").onTapGesture {
            navController.navigateTo(.userView("123"))
        }
    }
}

struct UserView: View {
    let user: String
    @EnvironmentObject var navController: NavigationController

    var body: some View {
        Text("GO TO POST").onTapGesture {
            navController.navigateTo(.postView("123"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I still have the same issue. You were correct in home the AppView is used, so the only difference I see here is that you used NavigationPath() instead, but that doesn't fix it for me. If this is working as expected for you then it may suggest it's caused by something else. Also I used NavigationLinks before but they caused other issues

Answer (score 0):

I took a while but I found the solution.

The issue was where I was declaring my `navigationDestination`.

I had the following setup (I had simplified it even more in my question).

```
    private let homeView = HomeView()   
    NavigationStack(path: $navController.homeNavPath) {
      homeView
    }
```

```
    public struct HomeView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var navController: NavigationController

    public var body: some View {
        Text("GO TO POST").onTapGesture {
            navController.navigateTo(PostView("123"))
        }.navigationDestination { ... }
    }
}
```

There seems to be two ways to fix this. Either I need to call HomeView() directly in the NavigationStack (but I am sure I was not doing that originally for some reason...) or I can move the `navigationDestiation{}`
call to be like either of these. All of these fix the issue, although I'm not 100% sure how:

```
    private let homeView = HomeView()   
    NavigationStack(path: $navController.homeNavPath) {
      homeView.navigationDestiation{...}
    }
```

or

```
    private let homeView = HomeView().navigationDestiation{...} 
    NavigationStack(path: $navController.homeNavPath) {
      homeView
    }
```

If anyone has an explanation for why this works that'd be appreciated